# How to adjust a big sidewaystable little bit lower vertically?

Tags: tables, rotating

[image]

The rotating's sideways table just crosses the Chapter title: how can I adjust the table vertically lower?

*Ps. Dealing with big tables, other solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290440/automatic-linebreaks-for-equations-in-tabular-environment) contains multilinebreaks where prob with breqn.*

Comment: Please provide the code and not just the screenshot. We can't reproduce the problem from a screenshot. You could adjust the layout dimensions for that page. You could omit the header on that page. You could lie to TeX about the size of the table, which is obviously too large for the space you are trying to fit it in, and lower it using something like `\raisebox`. But it would almost certainly be better to adjust the table to be less tall-and-skinny. I don't understand the cryptic remark about the linked solution at the end. Probably the code will help clarify it when you update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is too wide for the page so the best solution would be use a different layout, however if you just want to move it to the left (down after rotation) use

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}.....

\end{sidewaystable}
```

Code untested as (again) you have provided no example.